При попытке скопировать репозиторий с github в github desktop вылезает ошибка clone failed




Cloning into 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\UNITY\VeryScareGame-main\VeryScareGame'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3675, done.        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (195/195), done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (115/115), done.        
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer
error: 407 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Would you like to retry cloning ?

Как решить проблему? Подскажите, пожалуйста.
